# Promise to iterate over an array of links, parsing them using mercury-client and pushing the parsed content into a new array

Tags: javascript, loops, promise, adonis.js

I have an array of links which I want to parse its contents using [`mercury-client`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mercury-client), and push the result into an `articles` array.

```
* parseLinks() {
  const links     = yield this.getInboxMessages() // It will be ['link1', 'link2', ..., 'linkN']
  const articles  = []

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    for (let link of links) {
      mercury.parse(link).then((data) => {
        articles.push(data)
      })
    }

    resolve(articles)
  })
}
```

I fail to see what's wrong, for I only get `[]`. I tried to move the `Promise` to within the `for..of`, but the result remained the same.

By removing the loop and making it parse only the first index of `links` array, I had no issues, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're resolving too early before `articles` ever gets filled.

You can replace your entire `return` block with this:

```
return Promise.all(links.map(link => mercury.parse(link)));
```

which will return a resolved promise only once every link has been handled.

If (and only if) the `mercury.parse` function can cope with being passed as a bare function reference without requiring that `mercury` is passed as the `this` context variable you could simplify further:

```
return Promise.all(links.map(mercury.parse));
```

Comment: Simple and easy. Thank you.

Comment: @JaromandaX I added your suggestion (with the appropriate caveat) to the answer

Answer (score 1):

You get `[]` articles because you call `resolve(articles)` sync'ly while your `for` loop pushes data in there async'ly. Instead of pushing resolved `data` into your articles, push `mercury.parse(link)` promises into an array. You will end up with an array of to-be-resolved mercury-client promises. You can then use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) on that array and resolve `articles` only when all depending promises have resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with `Array.prototype.reduce` and `Promise.all` combination. Something like below.

```
function parseLinks () {
  const links = [....]

  return Promise.all(links.reduce((promises, link) => {
    return promises.concat(mercury.parse(link))
  }, []))
}

parseLinks().then(links => console.log(links))
```